# Windows batch, how to automate RoboCopy in Compare mode, not Copy mode?

Tags: windows, batch, robocopy

This RoboCopy Compare command below is working fine,
it is comparing 2 folders and
outputs results to a text file and
if there is a difference between 2 folders
then text file has at least **5 phrases** embedded:

***EXTRA Dir

*EXTRA File

New File

New Dir

Older**

ROBOCOPY.EXE options:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx
https://www.mydigitallife.net/robocopy-syntax-command-line-switches-and-examples/

Command in use is:

```
ROBOCOPY.EXE D:\Temp S:\1\Temp *.* /V /FP /BYTES /L /S /E /COPYALL /DCOPY:T /NP /XJ /R:9 /W:9 >S:\LOG_files\Output.txt
```

exit code = 0  while testing the above command with

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

The text file shows there is a problem with the compare
because the text file has phrases such as:
***EXTRA Dir

*EXTRA File

New File**
Etc…

but the RoboCopy exit code = 0 and
zero (0) exit code also makes sense
because No files were copied
because Robocopy switch is /L
/L :: List only - don't copy, timestamp or delete any files.

Question is:
**How to elegantly use RoboCopy to compare folders in a Windows batch?**

Said differently,
Use RoboCopy in compare mode (List Only mode) in a Windows batch and
RoboCopy detects IF 2 folders are identical or
RoboCopy detects IF 2 folders have a difference and
batch notifies user of RoboCopy results regarding these 2 folders.

--

Comment: You need to examine `Output.txt` in your batch file to decide whether there are any differences.

Comment: Agreed, examine OUTPUT.TXT   How to automate the examination? -- How to gracefully catch all the “phrases“ RoboCopy sends to OUTPUT.TXT?  There are at least 5 Phrases: *EXTRA Dir, *EXTRA File, New File, New Dir, Older  --  What is the suggested way, suggested mechanism, to automate the examination of a TEXT file and to catch these 5 RoboCopy phrases?   (There might be more than 5 RoboCopy phrases)

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The question is about a stuck point -- the "mechanism".  The question is about: Which program to use?  Is a third party program suggested that works in a batch?  or a Microsoft program recommended?  The question is not about someone writing a script.  The question is about what tool?  What program?  What .EXE? to use for what was done manually above.  How to automate process using above RoboCopy script command that gave above OUTPUT.TXT  --  Stuck point#1:  Suggest a way or Recommend a way?   Stuck point#2:  What tool?  What program?  What .EXE?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the tool, use the batch command FINDSTR. This [page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/findstr.php)  on the command gives an example of how you can automate finding just the differences in a Robocopy compare.